# Mathematical notation for getting an index

Tags: notation

Imagine we have the following set $A = \{a,b,c,d\}$ and we consider vectors which represent orders in that set. For example, I'd write $\vec{v} = (d,b,a,c)$ for the ordering $d > b > a > c$.

In this context, given an element $x$, is there a specific mathematical notation that allows me to get the index of elements $x$ in $\vec{v}$?

Following the example above, I'd like to get something like $f(\vec{v},a)=3$ and $f(\vec{v},d)=1$.

Comment: ${\bf v}_3$, etc.

Comment: But what if e.g. $\vec{v}=(a,a,a,a)$? And what would be the value of $f(\vec{v},e)$ in your example?

Comment: Where are assuming that these vector have unique values in each position.

Comment: You can always define it yourself $$f(\vec{v},v_i):= i$$?

Comment: I'm currently doing that. I have the feeling that there is some notation for this, but I can't remember it. :(